# Throwaway buffer when necessary

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following function where I don't care about the `tmp` buffer required as an argument and only need the function's return value. For example:

```
char tmp[20];
printf("Using my function for case 1: %s", printstr(28, tmp));
```

Is the following an acceptable way to do the above?

```
printf("Using my function for case 1: %s",
   printstr(28, (char[20]){0})
);
```

Is that an acceptable approach? Or are there any downsides of using that approach?

Comment: The readable one would be my preference.  And you can always put that code in a scope block if you're really concerned about 20 bytes lying around on the stack.

Comment: @paddy oh good point, thank you. I always forget about being able to use scope blocks outside functions and loops.

Comment: @paddy Those 20 bytes will be on the stack in the second case too. I think the two ways are essentially the same

Comment: @PaulHankin you're saying that stack allocation for that array remains after `printf` returns in the second case?  This is what the question is about.

Comment: In the first case I'd suggest calling it `dummy` or `unused` rather then `tmp` - that better documents the idiom.  The question is possibly a matter of opinion - so not really a valid SO question. The second is not compilable as C++ ("taking address of temporary array") which may be a consideration.

Comment: @paddy I wrote my research up as an answer. Yes, the array remains until the end of the enclosing block, and the standard is pretty straightforward about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 6.5.2.5 paragraph 6 of the C standard says of compound literals:

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
> initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
> outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
> duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
> the enclosing block.

So the two forms of the function call in your question are essentially the same.

Other than readability or subjective concerns, there's no reason to prefer one form to the other -- they have identical meanings as written.